# Display several graphs with shared vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the two graphs:

```
gr1 = Graph[{DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[3, 2]}, EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[x, i], {i, 3}]]
```

> [image]

```
gr2 = Graph[{DirectedEdge[4, 1], DirectedEdge[1, 5], DirectedEdge[5, 2], DirectedEdge[2, 6], DirectedEdge[6, 3], DirectedEdge[3, 7]}, EdgeStyle -> Red, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[x, i], {i, 3}]]
```

> [image]

I am looking for a way to display both graphs together, such that they are connected at the shared vertices `x1,x2,x3`. Ideally, it should look like:

> [image]

I tried something like `GraphPlot[{gr1,gr2}]` but this syntax seems flawed. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The union can be computed using [`GraphUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphUnion.html).  It constructs a new graph containing the vertices and edges from both.

Styling and other properties are lost and need to be re-added.

Comment: This works well, thanks! But is there a way to force the labeled vertices to be on a straight line, while the other ones go in zig-zag?

Comment: @Kagaratsch I don't know of any automatic way. You can always set vertex coordinates manually, even copy them from the two graphs. But I don't know how to set only *some* vertex coordinates and leave the rest to an automatic layout.

Comment: @Kagaratsch, maybe `GraphUnion[gr1, gr2, 
 VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[x, i], {i, 3}], 
 GraphLayout -> "MultipartiteEmbedding", 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  Thread[EdgeList[gr1] -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Black]],
 VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[gr1] -> Black], BaseStyle -> Red]`?

Comment: Wow, this is great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
props = {EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Red,  DirectedEdge[1, 2] | DirectedEdge[3, 2] -> Black}, 
   ImagePadding -> 10, 
   VertexLabels -> { j_ :> j, i_ /; i <= 3 :> Subscript[x, i]}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> (Composition[ScalingTransform[{1, .25}], 
       ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}], RotationTransform[Pi/2]][GraphEmbedding[g2]])};

SetProperty[g2 = SetProperty[GraphUnion[gr1, gr2], 
    GraphLayout -> "MultipartiteEmbedding"], props]
```

[image]

Note: For this particular case, you can also use `EdgeAdd[gr2, EdgeList @ gr1]` instead of `GraphUnion[gr1, gr2]`.